# Scheduled Reminders

Tags: wordpress, scheduled-reminders, cron-job

**Wordpress (latest) v 5.4 and CiviCRM 5.23.0**

Scheduled membership reminders are scheduled daily, have been and are still going out correctly as far as I'm aware.  The log entries show the following but it never gives a follow-up success message.

> List of log entries for: Send Scheduled Reminders
>   Entity: Job Action: send_reminder
>   Summary
>   Starting execution of Send Scheduled Reminders
>   Details
>   Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
>   a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}
>   Full message: 
>   Starting execution of Send Scheduled Reminders

The log entries have been like this for quite some time. CRON is working OK.  If this job is run manually through 'Execute Now', I get a Wordpress message "There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions. Learn more about debugging in WordPress".  However the job does run successfully.

The CRON settings are 
wget -O - -q -t 1 'https://www.XXX.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=XXX&pass=XXX&key=XXX'

My question is, should I be concerned about not getting a success message in the Scheduled Jobs Log?

Comment: What does the email sent to the site admin say?

Comment: Thanks Aidan for your response.  The message is the same as in an email and says "There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.Learn more about debugging in WordPress" and is in a page with HTML from .../wp-admin/admin.php/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fjob&action=export&id=8&reset=1
I don't get any other message.  Hope this helps

Comment: Ah ok, sometimes the email has different information.  Is there anything in the Civi log?  Do you get any messages if you run that wget from a shell?

Comment: The only comment in the civi log says "Apr 16 08:01:32  [warning] CiviCRM thinks site is not SSL, redirecting to {url}  Array(
    [url] => https://mywebsite.org/support-us/donations/)
But I don't think this is relevant to the problem I'm having.  Every time scheduled reminders runs, I do not get a success or failure message.
I'm afraid I don't have shell access.